# My return data form AFNetworking JSON is not displaying properly

Tags: ios, api, afnetworking

experiencing a problem now. Tried googling around for solutions but still unable to get any. Would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this

Basically I'm consuming OneMap API using AFNetworking library. The return data that i get, when i NSLog it, the : is replaced with = while the [ are replaced with (

And apparently, the POST approach doesn't work, does OneMap only support GET?

When i convert it to a string and encode it with UTF8 it logs in the proper format, but i'm unable to retrieve keyvalues from the string directly right?

Here is a snippet of the code i'm using to consume it :

-(void)getDrivingDirections:(NSArray *)coords destination:(NSArray *)dest
{

```
NSString *destination = [dest componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *currentLocation = [coords componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *routeStops = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@;%@",currentLocation,destination];



NSString *dataURL = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/route/solve?token=%@&routeStops=%@",tokenString,routeStops];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURL]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:dataURL
                                                  parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [MMProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"Something went wrong :("];
}];

[operation start];
```

}

Here is a snippet of the return : http://pastebin.com/Sa0U0tYf (too long to post it here directly)

Thanks!

Comment: What does the NSLog look like?

Comment: The NSLog return is included in the last link. The link to pastebin. It's basically my whole NSLog return for the api consumption

Comment: How is it not displaying properly?  Looks like you have a dictionary.  When you print to the console, it'll print in that format.

Comment: The : used in JSON is now turned into = and also the [ used is turned into (

Usually other JSON that i have consumed, i can access it using [[data objectForKey:@"directions"] objectForKey:@"features"]. But in this case, this crashes.

Comment: Ya, that's how it gets printed.  Try assigning your response to an NSDictionary.  Once you do that, you'll be able to manage the response easily.

Comment: @jownsftw, have you tried any of the solutions that we have proposed? If so, you should check any answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect JSON to be returned, why don't you try to use `AFJSONRequestOperation`? The response object will be a `NSDictionary` with the contents of the JSON response, parsed with built-in `NSJSONSerialization`.